# Orientation For One Navigation Container ios

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, orientation

I have one View Controller (`BaseViewController`), and in that i have created two containerView.(Top and Bottom)

In the Top Container view i am Displaying One View controller which is responsible to Play Video

In the Bottom i am Calling Navigation Controller Stack - To display some Controller that user can navigate.

Now I want my Top Container to Rotate on Orientation change , but bottom should be always Portrait.

I have created function in **`AppDelegate`:**

```
internal var supportedOrientaion:SupportedOrientaion?
     func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

            if let supportedOrientaion = supportedOrientaion {
            switch supportedOrientaion {

                case .AllButUpsideDown:
                    return .AllButUpsideDown
                case .LandscapeOnly:
                    return .Landscape
                case .PortraitOnly:
                    return .Portrait
            }
            } else {
                return .Portrait
        }

    public enum SupportedOrientaion:Int {
        case AllButUpsideDown = 0
        case LandscapeOnly
        case PortraitOnly
    }
```

and then from My Top View Controller -> i am adding Orientation Observer

```
func addObserver() {
let  appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
      appDelegate.supportedOrientaion = .AllButUpsideDown
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ProjectDetailVideoViewController.OrientationDidChange(_:)), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

//CallBack

```
    func OrientationDidChange(notification:NSNotification) {

  //Handle My case here
    }
```

But now problem is my Bottom View Controller also gets rotated.

I know because as supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow has become "AllButUpsideDown" .
I want to know how can i disable Bottom View Rotation at same time .
You can think i want to implement Controller like YouTube.
Where Top controller Plays Video and Bottom Remains Static. and when user rotate iphone only Top gets rotates.

Comment: Do you want that the top one becomes fullscreen ?

Comment: yes u r right. like youtube, I am able to make Top one full screen and then back to normal. i just want my bottom view to remain static always , i.e it should not give feel that bottom is also rotating

Comment: Have you tried to change the constraints of your top container to be fullscreen and then when you return back to portrait you return back to your first setup of constraints?

Comment: yes mejdi , i am currently doing like that only. but it rotates first